# AJAX XML parseerror

Tags: xml, jquery, asp-classic

For the following AJAX call:

```
type: "POST",
url: 'myClientSideHandler.asp',    
data: {param1: "value1", param2: "value2",param3: "value3"},
dataType: 'xml',
success: function(response)
{
    myFunction();
},
error: function(xhr, status, error) 
{
    myOtherFunction();
},
```

i am getting an erorr that says "parseerror" and the response only contains the closing tag of the ROOT element for some reason.  I am making a number of different calls that get XML back and this is only happening to a handful of items.  the call takes a relatively long time to complete.  Oddly, in Firefox, there is no error and the response is empty XML.

I have verified that there are no errors in the XML.  the only thing that I noticed is that some of the errors are happening for particularly large items.  I have changed my IIS settings to the max response size. I also tried making this a "GET" to no avail.

i am also using asp classic for the server side (i know, i know)

Any ideas?

Comment: what happens if you access the xml directly?

Comment: as a test, i accessed the XML directly with no issues, however this is not a solution that will work for our purposes

Comment: this is just to make sure the xml works fine ;) only thing i could imagine, that the parser stumbles upon something unusual... you parse with asp classic??

Comment: yes asp classic does the parsing in an asp classic page (i didn't chose it...) that parses correctly for other XML input

Comment: on the asp page that's creating the xml, have you set the content type? response.ContentType = "text/xml" - That's caught me out before...

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but yes i have the content type set.  

i just realized that the file is almost 5MB in size (!), however i can't find a limit anywhere.  perhaps it is a javascript limit?

Comment: Js does not care much about filesize. Only processing might take a while